# Study about Path-connectednes

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I know about connectedness and path-connectednes. But I got stuck while working out following problem. $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2<1\}\cup\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:y=1\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2.$ Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any point in the set can be connected to $(0,1)$ by a line segment. Hence the set is path connected.